# limit users in wordpress to access special posts

Tags: wordpress

In **Wordpress** I have a post-type named "my-catalog".

There is some posts with `post_type="my-catalog"`. Also I have some users that they roles are "operator".
So I want each operator see and access special posts.
For example operator-1 can only see and access posts[1,2,3] and operator-2 can only see and access posts[4,5].

I searched and tried some plugins. But none of theme meet my demand. 
How is such thing possible?

Comment: Kindly add some code and some more info so one can help you easily, elaborate more

Answer (score 0):

you can try "Ultimate Membership Pro".